# Loding image is not appearing in the center of my main page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using a loading gif image to be shown while the main page is loading, however it shows on the side as shown below and I am not sure why?

[image]

My code:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'interactive') {
    document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility = "visible";
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

```css
#load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: url('../../images/page-loader.gif') no-repeat center center
}
```

```html
<div id="load"></div>
```

Comment: What has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: The application itself is in php and he html in embedded in php as phtml

Comment: Are you looking for vertically and horizontally center ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there is something additional in your CSS or HTML that disturbs your spinner. In the example below it works fine.

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'interactive') {
    document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById('contents').style.visibility = "visible";
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

```css
#load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('https://68.media.tumblr.com/695ce9a82c8974ccbbfc7cad40020c62/tumblr_o9c9rnRZNY1qbmm1co1_500.gif') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<div id="load"></div>
<div id="contents">
  this is my page
  </div>
```

Comment: Worked but after removing   background-size: 25px;
 and   position: fixed;
Could you please update them so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: Updated, but the spinner looks hugs now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mmm...a simple example is spinner push inside another DIV. Something like this.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bRRqoy

```css
div {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  background-color: red;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Also you can try with Fontawesome, you can use their helper classes and make more easy you example.

Regards

Comment: Thanks Alex, but it still not working, showing the samething

Comment: Can you make the example en codepen, will more easy help you. @SMH